# Integrating Facebook & Twitter buttons with InstaClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter

So today I found this awesome piece of code that instantly made my website faster. Actually, any link clicked became almost instant. It's called InstaClick (http://instantclick.io/). I installed it and everything worked great ..except that Facebook Like and Twitter Tweet buttons suddenly didn't show up anymore.

I searched their documentation on http://instantclick.io/scripts for a solution and found out it might be possible by changing the .on('change') code. But the problem is, the Facebook script:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and the Twitter script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src= "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

don't seem to use these codes to initiate it. Has anyone found a way to get this working? InstantClick seems like a wonderful way to speed up websites and if it worked with Twitter and Facebook it might just revolutionize the way the internet works.

UPDATE #1:

I found out how to fix Twitter by including it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

But including Facebook sdk.js the same way doesn't work. Any ideas?

UPDATE #2:

Just a thought, maybe a fix would be to check if Facebook or Twitter .js are loaded and if not, load them again?